# Buffer overflow Rooting vs SU via recovery?

Tags: android, buffer-overflow, rootkits, binary-code

After researching on rooting processes low level details and techniques  i found that it happens mostly through Buffer overflow to gain root access via running payload ( binaries ) at return call address of memory.

**Method A ( BUffer Over flow to gain Root )**

Buffer over flow as briefly i understood is  it will :

1, exploit i.e tricking the buffer overflow and return calling address of procedure for further execution continuation.
2, inject the binary = payload , i.e actual code which do the job from that return address ( memory address ) from buffer to keep going the execution whcih actually do some act ( which still i am not able to understand in rooting case ) .

**Method B Chain Fire SU flashing via recovery**

the second method as refereed [here](https://theunlockr.com/2016/01/31/how-to-root-the-samsung-galaxy-j1-ace/)

Question :

*what is the difference between two methods...  is method A is completely encapsulated in Method B ??  what i understand is that there that in method B there is*

1. *script -->  which run do the exploit and then inject the binary
2. the Binary ---> contains the code to remount the system as root post exploit ( post getting root rights by changing current UID of process) and deploy the su.apk file with su rights ?*

i am unable to understand how a complicated method of buffer overflow can encapsulated in just a zip can become just a matter of flashing to get root of latest device which even kingroot cannot root. .

can any one explain the binary part ( how actually get the root access ) in **method A** and what is the step by step thing in **method B** .